# Vue-router: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

As a newbie started in vue 3, I have a question regarding the router. I am following the tutorial on [Vue School](https://vueschool.io/lessons/vue-router-named-routes-and-params). It seems okay until using the named routes and params. It renders a blank page with `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` in the console. What I’ve noticed is that the default code given is slightly different from the tutorial, but I think that is not the main issue. I asked on the forum as well, but no luck.

Here is the code, I’ll try to minimize the project to the workable code.

[src/main.js]

```
// instantiate the App
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

[src/App.vue]

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <TheNavigation />
      <!-- In this single page, without router-view, views cannot render -->
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TheNavigation from "@/components/TheNavigation"
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    TheNavigation
  },
}
</script>
```

[src/views/Home.vue]

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>All Destination</h1>
    <div class="destinations">
      <div v-for="destination in destinations" :key="destination.name">
        <!-- the named routes will link to the components, and its params can access the properties -->
        <router-link :to="{ name:'DestinationDetails', params: { id:destination.id } }">
          <h2>{{ destination.name }}</h2>
        </router-link>
        <figure>
          <router-link :to="{ name:'DestinationDetails', params: { id:destination.id } }">
            <img :src="require(`@/assets/${destination.image}`)" :alt="destination.name">
          </router-link>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import store from "@/store.js"

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      destinations: store.destinations
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[src/views/DestinationDetails.vue]

```
  <template>
  <!-- should render the id -->
  <!-- <h2>The destination is: {{ this.$route.params.id }}</h2> -->
  <h2>The destination is: {{ $route.params.id }}</h2> <!-- turn out to be the correct way -->


  <section class="destination">
    <h1>{{ destination.name }}</h1> <!-- throw error, but ok in the tutorial -->
    <div class="destination-details">
      <img :src="require(`@/assets/${destination.image}`)" :alt="destination.name">
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import store from '@/store.js'
export default({
  data() {
    return {
      // pass the route id to use dynamic routing in the router/index.js file
      destinationId:this.$route.params.id
    }
  },
  computed: {
    destination() {
      return store.destinations.find(
        destination => destination.id === this.destinationId
      )
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

[src/router/index.js]

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/brazil",
    name: "brazil",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "brazil" */ '@/views/Brazil')
  },
  {
    path: "/details",
    name: "DestinationDetails",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "DestinationDetails */ '@/views/DestinationDetails')
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

[src/views/Brazil.vue]

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>
      Brazil
    </h2>
  </div>
</template>
```

[src/store.js]

```
// shrink down to have basic information
export default {
  destinations: [
    {
      name: "Brazil",
      slug: "brazil",
      image: "brazil.jpg",
      id: 1
   } ]
   }
```

**Edit1**

Thank @Boussadjra Brahim for the route issue, it should be `$route.params.id` instead of `this$route.params.id`.

```
DestinationDetails.vue?d5a2:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Proxy.eval (DestinationDetails.vue?d5a2:2)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:1166)
    at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5201)
    at reactiveEffect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42)
    at effect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5154)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5113)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5071)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4673)
    at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5274)
```

Now the issue remains in the `DestinationDetails` that `destination.name` is undefined but successful in the tutorial. I apologize for re-ordering and re-editing the post.

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176832/vue-2-mixin-doesnt-work-properly-in-v-for-vue-warn-error-in-render-typeer/68177228#68177228

Comment: I am trying to follow the tutorial, but the tutorial use `this.$route.params.id` exactly. Now I am using the property in the `store.js` such as `destination.name` but got the same issue. May I ask what I should do, or any documentation I can follow? Thanks, again. (I'll add the section in the template)

Answer (score 1):

@Woden within the Vue template you can leave out the `this` keyword.
The same applies to your data properties, computed properties, and methods.
The Vue docs are great. [Here's](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) a link to the template syntax which explains the above.

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned in the comment, @Boussadira solved the route issue, but I am keeping to the same issue but with data properties.

Answer (score 0):

Build your component using the `defineComponent` function to get the global properties inference:

```
<script>
import store from '@/store.js'
import {defineComponent} from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
 
  computed: {
   destinationId(){
        return this.$route.params.id
    },
    destination() {
      return store.destinations.find(
        destination => destination.id === this.destinationId
      )
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Tried, but remain the same. It seems that `destination.name` is the wrong usage here in vue 3.